# Is my computer haunted?

Tags: bug

When I am on a SE site, and reading, my hands off the mouse and keyboard, often the page will just shift a few inches vertically, for no apparent reason, as if there were a mischievous ghost sitting beside me, moving the mouse.

Is this a known SE phenomenon, or possibly something wrong with my machine?

I am using Chrome.

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons that cause this. Maybe the page didn't fully load and some images get inserted, or some script results in some minor changes. Can you make a video of your screen? That would be useful. You could use any gif screen capture too available online.

Comment: I'd have to edit the resulting video too, since the motion doesn't occur immediately but after several minutes.  I don't consider any change which shifts the page at all "minor", but especially a change that shifts it several inches. That falls into PITA territory, IMO. It is downright irksome. I was hoping to express that sentiment in my question, but my bowdlerized expletive was edited out.

Comment: We don't do anything that would shift the page several inches - on the question page we do add a div when the post was edited, but this is one line. We do the same on the homepage (on most sites) when new questions are posted - again only one line. I have seen this happen with faulty scroll wheels - a scroll signal is sent which would cause this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @Oded: I thought it might be something like that, and so replaced my mouse, but it still happens. It happens at work and at home, too. Both machines are running Windows 7 x64 with the same m/b,  Both have two monitors attached.

Comment: What page/pages does it happen on?

Comment: It has happened on SO and on English Language Learners, the two sites I frequent most often, the former out of my vast ignorance, the latter out of my vast knowledge :)

Comment: Does it happen on the home page, question page, other pages, all pages?

Comment: You really have to give us more: Which version of Chrome? What site and page does this happen? Did you try disable all browser extensions? Does it happen on other browsers? Does it happen when you are outside your current place?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: It happens as I'm reading a question on these sites, or as I am in the middle of responding to one, but have taken my hands off the input devices and am thinking of what  further to write.  Now that I know it is not something already well known, I can go through the troubleshooting steps of disabling add-ins etc.

Comment: It could be something as simple as a super-sensitive mouse wheel that gets jostled when my wrists bump the edge of the desk, or something like that.  The replacement mouse I got was the same model.  I just can't get it to happen at will, so it's less likely, but still possible. But that's exactly the visual behavior, like someone moved the mouse wheel a tad. The page shifts downward.

Comment: Chrome 53.0.2785.116

Answer (score 7):

I just had a similar behavior when I was editing an answer of mine.

I identified several reasons for *apparent scrolling:*

- New comments
- Question has been edited notification
- Other answer has been edited notification
- Time of comments changes (i.e. *59 minutes ago* to *1 hour ago*) causes line break to appear or vanish

Comment: Last bullet (time stamps) is correct, and not only for comments.